# unable to run solr on tomcat in linux(404 not found /solr)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, solr

I am trying to integrate solr on tomcat. I have tried from almost a couple of blogs

> http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/01/if-you-want-to-configure-solr4_19.html
>   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat

But every time I am faced with the 404 not found page when trying to run-

> localhost:4040/solr-4.4.0

On trying to start the webapp from tomcat manager its throwing

> FAIL - Application at context path /solr-4.4.0 could not be started

I have checked the catalina.logs file

> Sep 27, 2013 10:30:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal SEVERE: Error filterStart Sep 27, 2013 10:30:09 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
>   [/solr-4.4.0] startup failed due to previous errors Sep 27, 2013
>   10:31:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO:
>   Deploying web application archive AM.war Sep 27, 2013 10:31:24 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile INFO:
>   validateJarFile(/root/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.21/webapps/AM/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar)
>   - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Any help here will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was change in the way logging is implemented in Solr version 4.3 and higher. Please follow the directions outlined in [Solr Logging - Using the example logging setup in containers other than Jetty](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging#Using_the_example_logging_setup_in_containers_other_than_Jetty) for steps on how to setup logging to work properly with Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied all jars from your solr home distribution to tomcat bin. make sure you copy all jars solr_home/bin & solr_home/bin/etc to tomcat lib folder and then give it a try.

Comment: Tried it, still facing the same issue.